# Determining double cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My modern algebra class is currently working on cosets and the theorem of Lagrange. I understand the concept of cosets, but the calculations of double cosets is completely stumping me. I could really use help working on this question.

Find all $(H,K)$-double cosets in $G$ where $G=D_{16}$, $H=\{1,r^4,sr,sr^5\}$, and $K=\{1,s\}$

I have that $D_{16}=\{1,r,r^2,\dotsc,r^7,s,sr,sr^2,\dotsc ,sr^7\}$ but don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Given $x\in G,$ and $H,K$ subgroups, the double coset is  $HxK=\{hxk\mid h\in H,~k\in K\}.$

Comment: @AmberGladman, I edited your title to reflect your actual question. The previous was a bit vague. If you don't like the edit, I won't be "hurt" if you change it back. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to work as you do when you calculate cosets! Because double cosets **partion** the group you have to calculate $HxK$ until you ran out of $x$ (which is guaranteed since you have a finite). I will calculate one example, namely $r^2$:

$Hr^2K=(Hr^2)K=\{r^2,r^6,sr^3,sr^7\}K=\{r^2,r^6,sr^3,sr^7,r^2s,r^6s,sr^3s,sr^7s\}$.

I leave it tou you to make simplify the exprasions using the realations of the Dihedral group. Think you can continue from here?

Comment: so would HrK=(Hr)K={r, r^5, rsr, rsr^5}K={r, r^5, rsr, rsr^5, rs, r^5s, rsrs, rsr^5s}

Comment: Not really, $Hr=\{r,r^5,sr^2,sr^6\}$, according atleast to what you defined $H$ to be in the question. maybe there is something wrong there?

Comment: Okay that is exactly what I was wondering, thanks.

Comment: Generaly in the site, if you find an answer thankful you also upvote (whether you asked the question or not) and if you are indeed the asker you can choose one of the answers as the best (which also awards you some reputation) :)